# What are the differences between dpm() and dsm()?

Tags: drupal

What are the differences between [`dpm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm) and [`dsm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

dpm() prints a variable to the ‘message’ area of the page using drupal_set_message(). The output and compact and less likely to break the layout of your page.

From the devel docs:

> A note from the devel module: dsm() is
>   a legacy function that was poorly
>   named; use dpm() instead, since the
>   'p' maps to 'print_r'.

I think we should trust the devel folks on that one.

Answer (score 6):

[`dsm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm) is legacy function. It's a call to [`dpm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm) as it is, so you should use `dpm()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`drupal_set_message()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message) is a Drupal core function that sets messages to be output on the next page view. `drupal_print_message()` is, I believe (based on the examples I found in Google), something people occasionally say by accident when they actually mean `drupal_set_message()`, but not a real function.

Note: there is a [`dpm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm) function in the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, which is short for "drupal print message" that outputs variables for development debugging.

Comment: Edited my question for clarification. I am using devel.

Answer (score 3):

They're all the same, check how [`dsm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/7) is defined (one is calling another):

```
function dsm($input, $name = NULL) {
  return dpm($input, $name);
}
```

So the main one which should be used is `dpm()`, as `dsm()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[Devel Demo](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_demo) is a good drupal module that demonstrate the most of the debugging functions provided by devel module and [here](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) is a good post which gives a brief overview of those functions.

Comment: you need to include the relevant information in your answer, not just link to offsite resources.